# Move directories that match given regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I try to move directories with their contents. Names of the directories are letters followed by digits:
`a2`,`a2321`, `sdadsa2321321`, so the regex would be `[a-zA-Z]+\d+`. However  it doesn't work.

```
$SourceDirectoryPath = "C:/directory/[a-zA-Z]+\d+"
$TargetFilePath = "C:/directory/target"

New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path $TargetFilePath
Move-Item -Path $SourceDirectoryPath -Destination $TargetFilePath -Force
```

If I replace `[a-zA-Z]+\d+` with simple wildcards like `a*` it moves moves multiples directories, this proves that `[a-zA-Z]+\d+` is the only incorrect part of the script.

**Question:** What is the correct form of the regex `[a-zA-Z]+\d+` in Powershell? This regex is fully correct in Java, but for some reason it doesn't work here.

Comment: `-Path` takes a ***wildcard*** rather than a regex. `[a-z]` can be used as a wildcard range, which means any character `a-z` or `A-Z`, and there are no quantifiers for the matched characters. So `[a-z][0-9]` would match `a9` and `B8` but does not match `aa7` or `Z10`. `?` can represent any character one time. `*` is 0 or more characters that don't have to match. So `[a-z][0-9]*` will match `a9` or `b6544` or `c4cdder32443`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
$sourceDir = 'D:\source'
$destDir   = 'D:\destination'

$pattern = '^.*[a-zA-Z]+\d+$'
$baseDir = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Recurse -Directory

foreach( $directory in $baseDir ) {

    if( $directory.Name -match $pattern ) {
        Move-Item -Path $directory.FullName -Destination $destDir -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this `.*` mean any string of chars 0+ length? Why is that important?

Comment: I always tray to match the whole expression to avoid side effects.

Answer (score 0):

To use regex matching on files and folders with `Get-ChildItem`, you will need to use the `Where-Object` clause.

This should do it:

```
$SourceDirectoryPath = 'C:\directory'
$TargetFilePath      = 'C:\directory\target'

# create the target path if it does not exist yet
if (!(Test-Path -Path $TargetFilePath -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $TargetFilePath -ItemType Directory
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDirectoryPath -Directory | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^[a-z]+\d+$' } | 
    ForEach-Object { $_ | Move-Item -Destination $TargetFilePath -Force }
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I replace `[a-zA-Z]+\d+` with simple wildcards like `a*` it moves moves multiples directories, this proves that `[a-zA-Z]+\d+` is the only incorrect part of the script.

Indeed: **The `-Path` parameter of file-related cmdlets can *only* accept *wildcard expressions*** (see [`about_Wildcards`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)), not *regular expressions* (regexes) (see [`about_Regular_Expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)).

- While distantly related, the two types of expressions are syntactically different: wildcard expressions are conceptually and syntactically simpler, but far less powerful - and not powerful enough for your use case. See [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings)' comment on the question for a quick intro.
- Also note that many PowerShell cmdlets conveniently also accept wildcards in *other* types of arguments (unrelated to the filesystem), such as `Get-Command *job*` allowing you to find all available commands whose name contains the word `job`.

By contrast, **use of *regexes* always requires a *separate, explicit operation*** (unless a command is explicitly designed to accept regexes as arguments), via operators such as `-match` and `-replace`, cmdlets such as `Select-String`, or the `switch` statement with the `-Regex` option.

In your case, you need to filter the directories of interest from among all subdirectories, by combining the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet with `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match); the syntactically simplest form is to use an *operation statement* (a cleaner alternative to passing a script block `{ ... }` in which `$_` must be used to refer to the input object at hand), as shown in the following command:

```
# Define the *parent* path of the dirs. to move.
# The actual dirs. must be filtered by regex below.
$SourceDirectoryParentPath = 'C:/directory'
$TargetFilePath = 'C:/directory/target'

# Note: If you add -Force, no error occurs if the directory already exists.
#       New-Item produces output, a System.IO.DirectoryInfo in this case.
#       To suppress the output, use: $null = New-Item ...
New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path $TargetFilePath

# Enumerate the child directories of the parent path,
# and filter by whether each child directory's name matches the regex.
Get-ChildItem -Directory $SourceDirectoryParentPath |
  Where-Object Name -match '^[a-z]+\d+$' |
    Move-Item -Destination $TargetFilePath -Force
```

Note that I've changed regex `[a-zA-Z]+\d+` to `^[a-z]+\d+$`, because:

- PowerShell's regex matching is case-*insensitive* by default, so `[a-z]` covers both upper- and lowercase (English) letters.
- The `-match` operator performs *substring* matching, so you need to *anchor* the regex with `^` (match at the start) and `$` match at the end in order to ensure tha the *entire* input string matches your expression.

Also note that I've used a *single*-quoted string (`'...'`) rather than a double-quoted one (`"..."`), which is preferable for regex literals, so that no confusion arises between what characters are seen by the regex engine, and which characters PowerShell *itself* may interpolate, *beforehand*, notably `$` and `` ` ``.